# Deploy classes on Production

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have 4 Apex classes I worked on and some that was already created but had to tweak it. I would like to deploy them on Production but facing some issues.
Let's start with the first one, **Code Coverage : 0%** I know I need to duplicate the classes and use @isTest in it and test it. What I don't know is what is to test? Like this code below, what do I need to test?:

```
    public class attachPDFToInvoice {
    
    private final Invoice__c a; //Invoice object
    
    //constructor
    public attachPDFToInvoice (ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        a = (Invoice__c)standardPageController.getRecord(); //instantiate the Invoice object for the current record
    }
    
    //method called from the Visualforce's action attribute
    public PageReference attachPDF() {
        
        //generate and attach the PDF document
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.Invoice; //create a page reference to our pdfDemo Visualforce page, which was created from the post https://interactiveties.com/blog/2015/render-visualforce-pdf.php
        
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',a.Id);
        
        Blob pdfBlob; //create a blob for the PDF content
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { //if we are not in testing context
            pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent(); //generate the pdf blob
        } else { //otherwise, we are in testing context and getContent() gets funky so create the blob manually
            pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('Some Text for a boring PDF file...');
        }
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = a.Id, Name = 'Invoice.pdf', body = pdfBlob); //create the attachment object
        insert attach; //insert the attachment
        
        //redirect the user
        PageReference pageWhereWeWantToGo = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view(); //we want to redirect the User back to the Account detail page
        pageWhereWeWantToGo.setRedirect(true); //indicate that the redirect should be performed on the client side
        return pageWhereWeWantToGo; //send the User on their way
    }

}
```

What would that do? What I don't understand is it's working on the sandbox, why do we need to add anything??? it's working :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes down to it, you need to test because you're working on the Salesforce platform, and Salesforce says you need to test.

Salesforce can only realistically enforce a requirement for a certain level of code coverage, but the real value that unit tests provide to us as developers are:

1. They give you something concrete you can point to as evidence that your code behaves as you expect it to
2. They are automated. Sure, it takes time to run them, but you're not going through and clicking buttons and entering data into fields for each apex class, visualforce page, or lightning component (and believe me when I say that could be *days* of running through test scenarios manually if you let it or have a big enough org)
3. When you make changes to your org (to the class, the SObject(s) it works with, or to some indirect dependency), tests help you figure out if anything has broken because of it (and they can let you know *before* you deploy changes, if your deployment/change management process has some discipline baked into it)

As for what you would test, it boils down to some generic advice.

If your class produces output, makes a change to the public state of other classes, or performs DML, you want to write a test to assert that what you *think* should happen actually *does* happen. For the input that your class takes (which can be data you pass into the class as well as data the class accesses such as other SObjects), you should give it both good input and bad input.

Some quick examples:

- You should have a test method that asserts that you do actually insert a new Attachment (and that it's related to the appropriate parent) when you call `attachPDF()`
- You should have another test method that asserts that the pageReferece your `attachPDF()` method returns is actually for the record you passed in
- An optional (but perhaps worthwhile) test would be to see what happens if you provide a `ApexPages.StandardController` instance for something other than an `Invoice__c` record (i.e. don't assume you'll always get good input)

Comment: Thanks @Derek for your answer, appreciate your explanation. I will check this out.